# Trouble with my first RESTful Web Services

Tags: web-services, rest, java-ee-6

i'm developing my firts RestFul webServices in javaEE6.
This is my Entity Bean

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private long idEntity;

 private String name;

 private String description;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity" , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<EntityB>  list;

  //Get and set
}

 @Entity
 public class EntityB {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private long idCategoria;

 @ManyToOne
 private MyEntity myEntity;

  }
```

this is my webServices

```
@Path("myentity")
@Produces( {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes( {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Stateless
public class MyEntityService {

 @Inject
 MyEntityDao entityDao;

 @GET
 @Path("{id}/")
 public MyEntity findById(@PathParam("id") Long id){
    return entityDao.findById(id);
 }
}
```

Finally i configured Jersey

```
@ApplicationPath("ws")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

Now  , if i try a invoke my web services (localhost:8080/xxxx/ws/myentity)  i get this error:

HTTP Status 500 - javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [com.sun.istack.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML

Answer (score 2):

You have a cyclic Graph of objects, which is not allowed , as it would result in an "infinite" XML.

MyEntity Holds a reference to EntityB , which holds a reference that goes back to MyEntity.

The marshaller will try to marshall MyEntity > EntityB > MyEntity > EntityB and so on.

You can mark MyEntity in EntityB as @XmlTransient, to avoid this.

However, It might not be a good idea to try to use the same Classes of objects across all your project (From persistence layers to communication layers).